# Media-queries bug when adapting the size of the screen

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I have installed Wordpress 3.6.1, and theGrid Retina Ready One-Page Wordpress Theme.
I have created two CSS classes "redback" and "greenback" in my theme, within Wordpress Dashboard, for my top-menu, in order to place on the right respectively the "ESPAÑOL" and "FRANÇAIS" buttons, as you can see on the website: [Website](http://lemendu.com)

I have settled all the mediaqueries files in order to adapt the website menu to the different sizes of the screens. And it works, except for the screen below width of 767px (on mobile phones).
The two words "ESPAÑOL" and "FRANÇAIS" don't line-up vertically with the other.
I have tried many solutions, but nothing works.

If I change the CSS classes "redback" and "greenback" to adapt it to the screen, then they don't match with the screen above width of 767px.
And if I put the CSS classes in my media-queries file in each category size of screen, nothing seems to work.

Have you any recommendations for it?

I thank you in advance, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with this in chromes dev tools and I think if you "reset" your two classes things will line up perfectly. So for example you could do:

```
    .redback, .greenback {
        padding: inherit
        margin: inherit
        etc.
    }
```

Kinda dirty though.
You could also just javascript the classes away at that screen size and just let them inherit the properties with the rest of the li's.

I am not a JS/jQuery expert by any means. In fact I know very little but based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943816/changing-a-class-name-with-jquery-given-a-specific-width-range-media-query) I put this together in a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/cpyle0819/pen/krEhD).
You just need to plug in your id's and class names where appropriate.

**HTML**

```
<p id="foo" class="blue">Color</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
  $(window).resize(function(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    if(width < 767) {
      $('#foo').removeClass('blue').addClass('red');
    }
    else {
      $('#foo').removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
    }
  }).resize();
```

Comment: I have just answered to you in the comment below. Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: added some example jQuery

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, the jQuery code is not totally that, but I think I'm about to have the solution.
Thank you for your time and consideration, I validate your response.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have tried the first method, but indeed, it's a little dirty. I want to try the second method, from javascript, but I am totally new to this. However, I have found the following code where I can change my CSS classes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){


    jQuery('#nav-button').click(function() {
            jQuery('#options li').toggle();
    });

    if ( jQuery(window).width() < 767) {
    jQuery('#options li a').click(function() {
            jQuery('#options li').hide();
    });
    }

    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  if ( jQuery(window).width() < 767) {
    jQuery('#options li a').click(function() {
            jQuery('#options li').hide();
    });
    }
    });

    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  if ( jQuery(window).width() > 767) {
            jQuery('#options li').show();
            jQuery('#options li a').click(function() {
            jQuery('#options li').show();
    });
    }
    });

});
```

But I don't know how to change it in order to apply what you have tell me before. (I only want to cut all the padding from the css classes "redback" and "greenback" off for the width < 767).