# Remove class when responsive style no longer applies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

so I've made a responsive menu that looks like the smartphone's menu (the one that slides from the side, Im not sure how it is called), and its toggler(which is an Anchor) is shown only when the screen is smaller than 960px using `@media screen and (max-width: 960px)`.
now to toggle the menu i use a JQ's `.toggleClass` to add a class to the body as shown here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-mobile-nav').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body').toggleClass('mobile-slide-nav');
    });
});
```

Now the problem is that when i stretch the window back to a bigger size than 960px after I open the menu the toggler disappears and the class that it added('.mobile-slide-nav') remains in the body element....

So... How do i fix it? any ideas?
And sorry about the bad english :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   console.log('resize called');
   var width = $(window).width();
   if(width > 960){
       $('body').removeClass('mobile-slide-nav');
   }
})
.resize();//trigger the resize event on page load.
```

src:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8943979/1632286